# Android InflateException FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android

I have recyclerview item's that I am trying to edit in terms of how they look. I tried adding a floating action button to each of the recyclerview's items but it threw this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Here is what each RecyclerView item is designed to look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shoeImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/air" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBrandName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="..."
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textShoeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="..."
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.698" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textBrandName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note... everything worked before adding the FloatingActionButton code. What could be the problem? The FAB button doesn't have an image, so it can't be loading any drawables that are too big. Thanks!

Comment: have you added design library in gradle?

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal working example? What happens if you remove the <TextView>s? What if you leave them and remove the FAB?

Comment: your code is working fine on my device. I believe it has something to do with your imports or maybe the constraint layout. Have you tried changing constraintLayout to any other layout ?

Comment: @Umair right the same code working fine in also in my device

Comment: @Prem yes I think either OP is checking it on some older versions of android or he haven't imported the supp library. like you said in your answer.

Comment: @Umair agree with you

Comment: Post your full fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile this in your build.gradle file-:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `android:layout_gravity` attribute of `FloatingActionButton`, 
You can either have `layout_gravity` as `bottom` or `top` but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you correct your design by adding the below attribute

```
 app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

Like this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textBrandName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: @Aaron post your gradle file